# Annotation effect on result

Tags: java, annotations

I saw this question yesterday:

[image]

Question was that which can be a result of this code?

```
1. 7654321
2. 765432
3. 76
4. 356742
5. 53143246
6. 53143245146
7. 357642
```

And the correct answer was 5.

Can anybody explain me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@BeforeClass` is executed before the class **Tests** is created. (5)

TESTCYCLE_1

`@Before` is executed before every test. (3)

`@Test` method **test1()** is executed. (1)

`@After` is executed after every test. (4)

TESTCYCLE_2

`@Before` is executed before every test. (3)

`@Test` method **test2()** is executed. (2)

`@After` is executed after every test. (4)

`@AfterClass` is executed after all test in the class **Tests** were executed. (6)

test7 will never be executed because it does not have a `@Test` annotation.

Comment: So, Whats your mean about `test`? Its on object of `Tests` class?  Or is a method?

Comment: A Test is a method with the `@Test`-Annotation. :) So test1() and test2() are tests.